Compatibility CPLEX 22.1 and Linopy
We are using the modeller Linopy for huge linear programming problems (millions of variables) and when we upgraded our version of CPLEX (22.1) suddenly the problem takes days and days to be solved.
Have you heard about this problem ?
Returns about this problem when changing version of CPLEX Linopy seems to have problems.

If you use linopy.model.Model.to_file to export the .mps file and use docplex to solve this mps, do you face the same issue ?
